# Вставка видео в окно Tkinter. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, видео

Какие нужны библиотеки для вставки видео в окно Tkinter? Желательно с примером.

Comment: этот пример не поможет: https://solarianprogrammer.com/2018/04/21/python-opencv-show-video-tkinter-window/ ?

Comment: Если использовать способ из ссылки, видео будет воспроизводится , но без звука и в черно-белом формате.

Answer (score 2):

Вот: Сам интересовался вопросом. Правда здесь есть и gif-ki для tkinter. Есть минус в том что воспроизводит немного медленнее чем надо. Лучше видео в gif переконвертировать.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import pygame
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip
import cv2


class AnimateGifLabel(Label):
    def __init__(self, *argv, image = None,  **kwargs):
        self.master = argv[0]
        self.filename = image
        self.check_cadrs()
        self.i = 0
        self.img = Image.open(image)
        self.img.seek(0)
        self.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img)
        super().__init__(*argv, image = self.image, **kwargs)
        if 'delay' in kwargs:
            self.delay = kwargs['delay']
        else:
            try:
                self.delay = self.img.info['duration']
            except:
                self.delay = 100
        #self.delay = 3 # Это минимально возможная задержка - иначе ткинтер не успевает обновится и не обновляет 2  (Но реагирует на события типа изменнения размера ) а при 1 даже не появляется
        self.after(self.delay, self.show_new_cadr)


    def check_cadrs(self):
        self.cadrs = Image.open(self.filename).n_frames
    def show_new_cadr(self):
        if self.i == self.cadrs:
            self.i=0
        self.img.seek(self.i)
        self.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img)
        self.config(image = self.image)
        self.i+=1
        self.master.after(self.delay, self.show_new_cadr)


class VideoLabel(Label):
    def __init__(self, *argv, video = None,  **kwargs):
        self.master = argv[0]
        self.filename = video
        self.video = cv2.VideoCapture(self.filename)
        cap = VideoFileClip(self.filename)
        audio = cap.audio
        audio.write_audiofile('$-python-tk-video-frame-audio.wav')
        pygame.init()
        self.sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('$-python-tk-video-frame-audio.wav')
        #clip = VideoFileClip(self.filename)
        #clip.write_gif("$~python-tk-video-label.gif")
        #self.filename = "$~python-tk-video-label.gif"
        flag, frame = self.video.read()
        self.image = self.tk_image(frame)
        super().__init__(*argv, image = self.image, text = '0 sec', compound = 'top',  **kwargs)
        self.sound.play()
        self.after(35, self.show_new_cadr)
        self.i=1
    def tk_image(self, cvframe):
        cv2.imwrite("$-python-tk-video-frame.jpg", cvframe)
        img = Image.open("$-python-tk-video-frame.jpg")
        return ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    def show_new_cadr(self):
        self.i+=1
        flag, frame = self.video.read()
        if flag == False:
            self.i = 0
            self.video.set(0, 0)
        self.image = self.tk_image(frame)
        self.config(image = self.image, text = str(self.i//24) + ' sec')
        self.master.after(35, self.show_new_cadr)



root = Tk()
root.title('Tkinter gif')
root['bg'] = 'white'
AnimateGifLabel(root, image = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes = (('GIF Animation Image', '*.gif'),('All files', '*.*')))).pack()
clipka = VideoLabel(root,  video  = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=(('MP4 Video', '*.mp4'),('All files', '*.*'))))
clipka.pack( expand =1 , fill = 'both')
root.mainloop()
```